# Add entity to EntitySet throw exception on submitchanges()

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm using Linq to Sql and have a Many-To-Many relation and therefore use a relation table.

When i try to insert data with relation/association i get error.

I use manual schema creation.

My simplified code:

First table/class Booklet has this association:

```
    private EntitySet<BookletChapterRel> _bookletChapterRel = new EntitySet<BookletChapterRel>();

    [Association(Name = "ep_booklet_ep_book_chap_rel", OtherKey = "BookletID", ThisKey = "BookletID", Storage = "_bookletChapterRel")]
    public EntitySet<BookletChapterRel> BookletChapterRel
    {
        set { _bookletChapterRel.Assign(value); }
        get { return _bookletChapterRel; }
    }
```

The BookletChapterRel has these two association:

```
    internal EntityRef<Booklet> _booklet;
    [Association(Name = "ep_booklet_ep_book_chap_rel", OtherKey = "BookletID", ThisKey = "BookletID", Storage = "_booklet", IsForeignKey = true, DeleteOnNull = true, DeleteRule = "CASCADE")]
    public Booklet Booklet
    {
        get { return _booklet.Entity; }
        set { _booklet.Entity = value; BookletID = value.BookletID; }
    }

    internal EntityRef<Chapter> _chapter;
    [Association(OtherKey = "ChapterID", ThisKey = "ChapterID", Storage = "_chapter")]
    public Chapter Chapter
    {
        get { return _chapter.Entity; }
        set { _chapter.Entity = value; ChapterID = value.ChapterID; }
    }
```

Chapter has this association:

```
    internal EntityRef<BookletChapterRel> _bookletChapterRel;
    [Association(OtherKey = "ChapterID", ThisKey = "ChapterID", Storage = "_bookletChapterRel")]
    public BookletChapterRel BookletChapterRel
    {
        get { return _bookletChapterRel.Entity; }
        internal set { _bookletChapterRel.Entity = value; ChapterID = value.ChapterID; }
    }
```

I try to make a simple insert:

```
Booklet b = new Booklet();
b.NumberOfPages = 0;
b.Title = "Hello";
b.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
b.DateModified = DateTime.Now;

bookletRepository.addBooklet(b); //Just calls booklettable.InsertOnSubmit()

var bookChapRel = new BookletChapterRel()
{
    ChapterID = 23,
    ViewOrder = 0
};

b.BookletChapterRel.Add(bookChapRel);

bookletRepository.SubmitBookletChanges();
```

But every time i get the exception:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ep_book_chap_rel_ep_booklet". The conflict occurred in database "easypiecy_v2", table "dbo.ep_booklet", column 'BookletID'.
```

If i do something similar with a EntityRef there is no problem.

What i'm i doing wrong? I have tried to do same thing on the same database with automatic schema generation and it worked fine.

Thanks, Michael.

Comment: You can enable logging using the DataContext.Log property.  This will inform you of the SQL that was run prior to the constraint violation.  Perhaps that will be helpful?

Comment: I have tried that, and i can see that it is trying to insert the relation with 0 as the bookletID, as like there was no association :S

Comment: Looking at your code, it's clear you are hand-rolling your LinqToSql objects, rather than using sqlmetal or the designer.  I used to do this, but when you make mistakes LinqToSql is just completely awful at messaging.  One problem I notice straight away is that your relationships are not bidirectional -- on sqlmetal generated classes, when you assign one side of the relationship, the generated code assigns the other side as well.  You are not doing this in your classes, and I suspect that is where the problem lies.

Comment: But my relationships is both way? Chapter has association to relation table and relation table has association to chapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it solved after examining the auto designers code:

**Instead of using:**

```
private EntitySet<BookletChapterRel> _bookletChapterRel = new EntitySet<BookletChapterRel>();
```

**I have to use the EntitySet overload like this:**

```
private EntitySet<BookletChapterRel> _bookletChapterRel;
```

Constructor:

```
public Booklet()
{
   _bookletChapterRel = new EntitySet<BookletChapterRel>(new Action<BookletChapterRel>(this.attach_ep_book_chap_rels), null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ChapterID = 23

May be the problem in that. Is your DB allow you to create BookletChapterRel with same ChapterID?

Is BookletID auto-increment in DB?

Comment: Not problem with chapterID, has tried with the auto designer and it worked.

BookletID is auto-increment.

Comment: Try to add the bookChapRel to DB: b.AddBookletChapterRel(bookChapRel); and then add to relation: b.BookletChapterRel.Add(bookChapRel);

Comment: Same result, it's strange, it should be such a simple operation :)